# Can't read FileReader.result more than once

Tags: javascript, firefox, filereader

Having a problem with FileReader in Javascript. I have a table row that I drop a file on to, and it works perfect the first time: I can get my string of file data. Drop it a second time, and nothing comes back.

Here's the rub:
- The .length property is the same
- The typeof() is the same (string)

But when I try anything, even alert(this.result), the second time (and any subsequent time) it does nothing: no errors, no exceptions, and it appears to be an empty string. Also: if I prepend some data on the string (length, type), it wipes out my entire string.

Here's the code:

```
function getFileData(file)
{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function()
    {
        alert(typeof(this.result) +"," + this.result.length + "," + this.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Output (first time only): "string,123456,data:image.jpeg,base64..."
Output (subsequent tries): (nothing)

No null, no undefined, and it wipes out the 'string,123456,...' if I put in the alert window.

FireFox 41, Windows 7 64.

Works in: IE11, Chrome 47

Comment: Are you dragging the same file, it may only provide the results of there is an onchange event

Comment: `FileReader.onload` is only called when `load` is fired. And `load` is only fired once.

Comment: @QBM5 I've tried different files, same result. Mike: A new FileReader is created with each drop operation, so readAsDataURL is called each time as well. It fails, without error/exception, and wipes out my string, when I access "this.result" on a new object on the second and subsequent times.